# Appcompat ActionBar Tab having Fragment Issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar-compat

```
public static class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, HomeActivity activity) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentOne();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentTwo();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentThree();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) 
        {
            case 0 : return "Fragment 1";
            case 1 : return "Fragment 2";
            case 2 : return "Fragment 3";
            //TODO
            default : return "";
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the adapter for view pager. The problem is :

> when clicking Tab 1, **onResume()** of **FragmentOne** and **FragmentTwo** get called.
>    going Tab1 to Tab 2, **onResume()** of **FragmentThree** called.
>    going Tab2 to Tab 3,  **onPause()** of **FragmentOne** called.
>    going Tab3 to Tab 2,  **onResume()** of **FragmentOne** called.

Why all the Fragments are called in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the way how ViewPager works. By default it stores three fragments: the one which is shown currently, one previous and one next (if present). If you want to prevent Pager from loading extra Fragments you may call its method [setOffscreenPageLimit(0)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int)), but actually I wouldn't recommend doing it. So it is not an issue it is working in a way it is intended to work.

UPD: By the way if you want to make your Pager more memory efficient, you may use [FragmentStatePagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) instead of FragmentAdapter, it actually destroys fragments instead of simply detaching them.

UDP2: I'm terribly sorry but offscreenPageLimit can be not fewer than 1. So in your case since your Fragment shows a ProgressDialog it passes its host Activity as context. That's why ProgressDialog shows up when adjacent Fragment is shown. So in onResume() method of your Fragment you should check [UservisibleHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint()) of the Fragment in order to check if this is the Fragment, shown to user. If it is true then show dialog if not, then dismiss it. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "blah-blah-blah", "blah-blah-blah");
    }
    else {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution not works for me.
I am showing the progress bar in Tab1. 
When I am going from Tab 3 to Tab 2. FragmentOne of Tab1 get Resumed and progress shown in Tab2. Can you just try it once.

Comment: Yes. And set it cancelable

Comment: Sorry, I've done a bit of research and I've found out that my initial answer was incorrect, please try solution in the second update

Comment: Can you please explain in detail, how can I use **UservisibleHint**?
    How can I replace **getActivity()** with  **UservisibleHint** in the Fragment?     I have used the **getActivity()** for Network hits also.     So, I have to make a check every where I have used **getActivity()**?

Comment: you shouldn't replace getActivity() with getUserVisibleHint() it's used only to check if the Fragment is currently visible. I've updated my answer with approximate code, maybe you'll need to make some corrections to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57492/discussion-between-user2733098-and-chaosit).